# WP7 RTM Emulator is displaying the framecounter and dx info on the rightside - is this the default?

Tags: windows-phone-7

Any application I create in the RTM version of the Windows Phone 7 tools displays the framecounter,memory and gpu diagnostic info along the right side of the emulator screen.

I did change any settings/preferences - is this the default behavior of the RTM emulator?

thanks
Michael

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The emulator no.  The apps by default, yes. (if the debugger is attached)

If you look in App.xaml.cs you'll find this code in the autogenerated constructor:

```
        // Show graphics profiling information while debugging.
        if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
        {
            // Display the current frame rate counters.
            Application.Current.Host.Settings.EnableFrameRateCounter = true;

            // Show the areas of the app that are being redrawn in each frame.
            //Application.Current.Host.Settings.EnableRedrawRegions = true;

            // Enable non-production analysis visualization mode, 
            // which shows areas of a page that are being GPU accelerated with a colored overlay.
            //Application.Current.Host.Settings.EnableCacheVisualization = true;
        }
```

you can comment out the enableframeratecounter if you want it off, or you can uncomment those others to get more stuff.