# why my WP7 App got a column of messy numbers at the right side of the screen?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

As shown in the image below, every time when I press F5/debug my app this line of messy numbers will appear at the right side of the emulator screen. Everything goes correctly as expected except this.

[image]

can anyone tell me why this strange thing happens? Thanks!

Comment: :)

please read this link : 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3840969/wp7-rtm-emulator-is-displaying-the-framecounter-and-dx-info-on-the-rightside-i

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are not quite messy.

Here is their meaning:

**First three numbers**: Render Thread FPS

**Second three numbers**: User Interface Thread FPS

**Third six numbers**: Texture Memory Usage

**Fourth three**: Surface Counter

**Fifth three**: Intermedia texture count

Explanation:

**Render Thread FPS**: The number of frames per second that the independent simple animations and rendering thread is using. Keeping around 60 will provide a great experience, while a number of 30 fps will begin to show a poor experience to the end user.

Under 30 fps this counter will turn red in post-beta builds.

**User Interface Thread FPS**: The number of fps that the primary user interface thread is experiencing. Property change notifications, data binding, primary managed code execution, and animations not handled on the render thread use this threads’ resources.

Turns red when the count is at or below 15 fps.

**Texture Memory Usage**: A specialized memory counter indicating the video memory used for storing application textures.

**Surface Counter**: A count of the number of surfaces that are passed to the graphics chip.

**Intermediate Texture Count**: The number of intermediate textures created for compositing.*emphasized text*

Reference: http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2010/07/counters/

Answer (score 0):

There is an article on MSDN titled "[Frame Rate Counters in Windows Phone Emulator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg588380%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)" that explains what the numbers mean and how to turn them off.