# How do I remove the debug string in the windows emulator?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [WP7 RTM Emulator is displaying the framecounter and dx info on the rightside - is this the default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3840969/wp7-rtm-emulator-is-displaying-the-framecounter-and-dx-info-on-the-rightside-i)

I want to take a nice screenshot of my app and send to a friend, but I got the silly debug string in the upper right corner. How to I remove it?

Seems to be numbers and shift if using acceleration for instance

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try running it as non-debug as you can:

- Use a release build instead of a debug build
- Use Ctrl-F5 instead of F5 to launch (so there's no debugger attached)

IIRC, that will prevent the diagnostic information from showing. It's probably that you only need to take one of these steps, but I couldn't tell you which offhand.

Comment: You can also turn it off permanently (on a per-app basis) by setting `Application.Current.Host.Settings.EnableFrameRateCounter` to false in the App.xaml.cs `App()` constructor.